# Convert words to phonemes in swift for iphone (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

MacOS has a method to convert words to [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme), in other words, sounds comprising part of a word such as 'oo' in the word pool.

[Words to Phenomes in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1448500-phonemes)

In addition, there appears to be a way to force pronunciation in certain ways by sending an attributedString to AVSpeechSynthesisVoice instead of a string as described in the link below so AVSpeechSynthesis knows about phonemes.

https://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/#customizing-pronunciation

However, I have been unable to find something that converts words to phonemes in IOS. If there is no native api, does anyone know of a workaround using Regex or perhaps a library.  Here is the method for MacOS.

Comment: I believe these methods are for the primitve speech synthesizers used many years ago. Any new voices won't support this at all.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have been unable to find something that converts words to phonemes in IOS.

I suggest to use the iPhone feature located at `Settings > General > Accessibility > Speech > Pronunciations` *(iOS 12)*.

This information comes from a detailed WWDC 2018 [video summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#IPA) and [code snippets](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) *(ObjC and Swift)* that explain how to import it in your code to be vocalized by the speech synthesizer.